# Nuxt.js Transpile files in server directory

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to transpile code in the `server` directory of a nuxt.js (version 2) project. I've amended the `config.nuxt.js` to transpile .js files within the server directory:

```
const pkg = require('./package')
const util = require('util')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Router config
  */
  // router: {
  //   middleware: 'check-auth'
  // },
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover'
      },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description },
      { name: 'application-name', content: '' },
      { name: 'msapplication-TileColor', content: '#000000' },
      {
        name: 'msapplication-TileImage',
        content: 'https://www.thejump.tech/mstile-144x144.png'
      },
      {
        name: 'msapplication-square70x70logo',
        content: 'https://www.thejump.tech/mstile-70x70.png'
      },
      {
        name: 'msapplication-square150x150logo',
        content: 'https://www.thejump.tech/mstile-150x150.png'
      },
      {
        name: 'msapplication-wide310x150logo',
        content: 'https://www.thejump.tech/mstile-310x150.png'
      },
      {
        name: 'msapplication-square310x310logo',
        content: 'https://www.thejump.tech/mstile-310x310.png'
      }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon.ico'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '57x57',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '114x114',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '72x72',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '144x144',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '60x60',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '120x120',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '76x76',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        sizes: '152x152',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon-196x196.png',
        sizes: '196x196'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon-96x96.png',
        sizes: '96x96'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon-32x32.png',
        sizes: '32x32'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon-16x16.png',
        sizes: '16x16'
      },
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.thejump.tech/favicon-128.png',
        sizes: '128x128'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'
      }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: ['normalize.css', '~/assets/style/app.styl'],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/vuetify',
    '@/plugins/gmap',
    { src: '@/plugins/vue-awesome-swiper', ssr: false }
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
    [
      'nuxt-sass-resources-loader',
      [
        'assets/scss/helpers.scss',
        'assets/scss/spacing.scss',
        'assets/scss/fonts.scss'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
  ** Apollo module configuration (See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/apollo)
  */
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4000'
      }
    }
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    // babel: {
    //   presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
    // },
    transpile: [
      /^vue2-google-maps($|\/)/,
      '/server/**/*.js'
      // /^\/?server\/(?:(?!\/)(?:.|\n))*(?:(?!\.js)(?:.|\n))*\.js$/
    ],
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import mongoose from 'mongoose'
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:316:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

... which means that it's not getting transpiled.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wring here?

Comment: why? its server code

Comment: ES6 modules. I want to move over code from a previous project which was transpiled.